# Combining data on matching columns

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

I have been fighting with a small problem in one of my macros:

I have to make an automatic report out of exported data from our ERP system. The data for one customer is registered over multiple data records however. I wish to combine these rows. Example:

```
Cust. Nr | Name    | prod 1 | prod 2 | prod 3 | prod 4
---------+---------+--------+--------+--------+-------
0001       Bla bla     3        0        4        7
0001       Bla bla     1        2        8        7
```

And then some 300 more rows of different clusters of customers. It differs how long these clusters are and if they are even directly behind each other.

I want to combine them so that the products are summed up in one data row.

I have tried some bits of VBA to solve this issue i however have not found the solution yet.

Maybe someone else can help me?

Comment: Is this the data on the spreadsheet and if so, what is your matching principle (as in are you looking to group by Cust. Nr)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are familiar with SQL my suggestion would be to treat your input data as a table on which you can perform an SQL query. you’ll need to ensure that the "Microsoft ActiveX Data Objects 2.0 Library" is referenced from the VBA Project (see bottom of answer).

Below example assumes your data from the question is in sheet1, headers in row 1 - you may have to remove the punctuation from the column headers e.g. `Cust. Nr` -> `Cust Nr` - I cant figure out how to escape that :o)

```
Option Explicit

Sub do_the_reporting()
  Dim conn As New adodb.Connection
  Dim path As String
  path = ThisWorkbook.path & Application.PathSeparator & ThisWorkbook.Name

  conn.ConnectionString = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source= " _
    & path & ";Extended Properties=""Excel 12.0;HDR=YES;"""
  conn.Open
  
  Dim rs As New adodb.Recordset
  Dim SQL As String
  
  SQL = "SELECT [Cust Nr], SUM([prod 1]), SUM([prod 2])  FROM [Sheet1$] GROUP BY [Cust Nr]"
  
  rs.Open SQL, conn
  
  While Not rs.EOF
    Debug.Print rs.Fields(0).Value, rs.Fields(1).Value, rs.Fields(2).Value
    rs.MoveNext
  Wend

  rs.Close
  conn.Close

End Sub
```

output

```
1             4             2             12            14
```

ADO:
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The easiest two ways I can think of is: use `PivotTable` or `Microsoft Access`.

To create a `PivotTable`:

1- Make sure your data is in a table (insert table).

2- Select the table.

3- Insert `PivotTable`.

4- Drag the customer number to rows.

5- Drag products to value.